# Discord JDA - How do I use VoiceChannelUpdateUserLimitEvent? (Java)

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Could someone explain how to use VoiceChannelUpdateUserLimitEvent with an example? I have tried to understand it, but it does not work for me. I am trying to change the user limit of a specific channel when executing a command.

JavaDoc: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/channel/voice/update/VoiceChannelUpdateUserLimitEvent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the userlimit of a channel you need the [`VoiceChannel`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/VoiceChannel.html) instance and update it using the [`getManager()`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/GuildChannel.html#getManager()) with [`setUserLimit`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/managers/ChannelManager.html#setUserLimit(int))

```java
public void setLimit(VoiceChannel channel, int limit) {
  channel.getManager().setUserLimit(limit).queue();
}
```

There are several ways to acquire a `VoiceChannel` instance:

- [getVoiceChannelById](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#getVoiceChannelById(long))
- [getVoiceChannelsByName](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#getVoiceChannelsByName(java.lang.String,boolean))
- [getVoiceChannels](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#getVoiceChannels())